# Can I import a component from a production build create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, create-react-app, antd

Does anyone know if it's possible to import a component from a production build create-react-app?

**Context:**

I have a CRA project that's built for production, in it there's a component called ExampleButton.
Now I create a second project with CRA, and I want to import ExampleButton from the first project.

**Is this at all possible?**
**I'm also open to alternative solutions.**

---

P.S. I have the source of the first project too, but my ExampleButton was created with 'antd' and when I import my ExampleButton from its .js file in the second project I get all sorts of errors. I can only assume antd was not designed to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if a production build of a react-app exports anything, if so, the component would not be accessible in the other application. Personally I would just copy paste the source code.

But if the two applications is going to run on the same webpage, I have some suggestions:

- Create a shared folder for components, you can import files from outside of the project context.
- [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna). Not really sure how it works with CRA though. You might have to do some configuration there (maybe even eject the app).